# _mm_prefetch and heap buffer overflow

Tags: c++, prefetch

I saw a piece of code that looked like this sample program:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

int main() {
  int arr[1024];
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
  }

  // Declare a pointer to the first element of the array.
  int *ptr = arr;

  // Loop over the array, using _mm_prefetch to prefetch data into the CPU cache.
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    _mm_prefetch((char *)ptr + 64, _MM_HINT_T0);

    // Do something with the current element.
    // ...

    // Increment the pointer.
    ptr++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Does this line in the program cause a heap buffer overflow towards the end of the loop?

```
_mm_prefetch((char *)ptr + 64, _MM_HINT_T0);
```

Or is it safe to prefetch memory outside the bounds of the array?

Comment: Quote: *if a memory fault is detected, a bus cycle is not initiated and the instruction is treated like a NOP*.